# How to use UltiSnips with SpaceVim?

Tags: neovim, plugin-ultisnips, spacevim

I'm trying SpaceVim and I would like to use the plugin UltiSnips with it, instead of Neosnippets that comes with it as default.
Based on what I found in http://spacevim.org/documentation, https://spacevim.org/layers and in :h SpaceVim I did what follows.
I added this to .SpaceVim.d/init.vim:

```
let g:spacevim_force_global_config = 0
let g:spacevim_snippet_engine = 'ultisnips'
" disable neosnippet to avoid conflict with UltiSnips
let g:spacevim_disabled_plugins=[
\ ['Shougo/neosnippet.vim'],
\ ]
" custom plugin
let g:spacevim_custom_plugins=[
\ ['SirVer/ultisnips/', {'on_ft' : 'autocomplete'}],
\ ]
let g:neosnippet#snippets_directory = '~/.SpaceVim.d/snippets'
```

I created manually a directory 'snippets' inside .SpaceVim.d and put a directory UltiSnips with my snippet file 'tidal.snippets', for [Tidal](https://tidalcycles.org/).
My snippets are like so:

```
snippet spr$ "spread ($)" i
spread ($) [ $1, $2, $3 $0]
  ${VISUAL}
endsnippet
```

My setup is Linux Ubuntu 17.10, Neovim, SpaceVim 0.6-dev

I'm getting this errors when I try to expand a snippet:

```
Error detected while processing function SpaceVim#mapping#tab#expandable:                                                                             
line    1:                                                                                                                                            
E117: Unknown function: UltiSnips#ExpandSnippetOrJump                                                                                                 
Press ENTER or type command to continue                                                                                                               
Error detected while processing function SpaceVim#mapping#tab#expandable:                                                                             
line    1:                                                                                                                                            
E15: Invalid expression: UltiSnips#ExpandSnippetOrJump()                                                                                              
Press ENTER or type command to continue                                                                                                               
Error detected while processing function SpaceVim#mapping#tab#expandable:                                                                             
line    2:                                                                                                                                            
E121: Undefined variable: g:ulti_expand_or_jump_res                                                                                                   
Press ENTER or type command to continue                                                                                                               
Error detected while processing function SpaceVim#mapping#tab#expandable:                                                                             
line    2:                                                                                                                 
E15: Invalid expression: g:ulti_expand_or_jump_res > 0                                                                                                
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

What I'm doing wrong? How could I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove

```
let g:spacevim_custom_plugins=[
\ ['SirVer/ultisnips/', {'on_ft' : 'autocomplete'}],
\ ]
```

no need to use custom plugin, just change `g:spacevim_snippet_engine` is enough.

If you still get issue, please use the issue tracker of SpaceVim github repo.

Comment: The errors stopped but it seams like the UltiSnip snippets file is not being found. Where should I put it?

Comment: I tried by adding this: ` let g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories=$HOME.'/.SpaceVim.d/UltiSnips' `  but it made no effect

Comment: oh, it is overrided in spacevim, I will fix it, the default value is ~/.SpaceVim.d/UltiSnips